How to generate compareTo method via openapi-generator-maven-plugin?
I want to generate the compareTo method via the openapi-generator-maven-plugin. The plugin generates all the methods defined in the pojo.mustache file namely equals(), hashCode(), etc. But it does not generate the compareTo method. I've tried adding the below to the OAS spec:
x-implements: ['java.lang.Comparable<MyClass>']

The resultant generated class implements Comparable as shown below:
public class MyClass implements java.lang.Comparable<MyClass>

I've tried overriding the pojo.mustache file by adding the below, based on an optional custom attribute in the OAS, but still the compareTo method does not get generated:
{{#vendorExtensions.x-custom-method}}
@Override
public String compareTo({{classname}} that)
{
    return "true";
}
{{/vendorExtensions.x-custom-method}}

Is there any predefined attribute that I can add in the OAS to generate it?

I don't have experience with open api, so I can't say if this is really a problem, but the method signature is wrong. Comparable#compareTo() returns an int, not a String, as in your example.
